# scanf store newline as the first element of the array

Tags: arrays, newline, scanf

hi I have a question about inputing data into array

why does scanf store `'\n'` into the first element of  the array in this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10
int main (void)
{
    // Global declarations
       int str_length;
       char str[MAX];
       int count;
       char temp;
    // Statements

       // prompt user for string length
       printf("Enter string length: ");
       scanf("%d", &str_length);

       printf("Enter string: ");
       // input string
       for(count = 0; count < str_length; count++)
       {
            scanf("%c", &str[count]);
            printf("%c", str[count]);
       }

       for(count = 0; count < str_length; count++)
       {    
            temp = str[0]; // set temp to the first element
            str[count] = str[count+1]; // set the next element to be the first element
            str[str_length-1] = temp;  // swap the first element and the last element
            puts(str);
       }


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

when I input `1234567890` into the array instead of 1 being the first element, the first element was the newline character `'\n'` instead.

thank in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you it get to here

```
scanf("%d", &str_length);
```

and the user type something like 4 followed by enter, your buffer filled with `4\n`.
The 4 goes to `str_length` and the `\n` stay at the buffer.
So you need to clean the buffer, simply by adding:

```
fflush (stdin);
```

**Notice** that when declear `char str[MAX]` and the user enter char's into it, you need to add null terminatior at the end of the string. 
Just add

```
str[str_length] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not have consumed the \n after getting the length on the lines

```
  // prompt user for string length
   printf("Enter string length: ");
   scanf("%d", &str_length);
```

All you should need to do is add a scanf of a %c just after this line and discard it.

Comment: what do you mean by comsumed the \n ? can you please explain in detail because i really want to know the reason why printf did not consumed \n. thank very much

Comment: scanf reads from stdin, where you are typing a number followed by \n.  scanf of a %d will not consume the trailing \n.  You need to consume it and throw it away.